# Как составить регулярное выражение для парсинга html?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть html который содержит в себе такой код для примера

```
<h3 id="z000"> 1. ОБЩИЙ СОСТАВ<br>РАЗДЕЛ 1. ОБЩИЕ ПОЛОЖЕНИЯ<br>Глава 1. ОСНОВНЫЕ ПОЛОЖЕНИЯ Часть 1. Тестовый заголовок</h3>
<p id="z1">      <b>Часть 16</b>. Размещение центра по траектории <br></p>
<h3 id="z001"> Часть 2. Положение гироскопа</h3>
<b><a name="z123"></a>  Часть 88. Определение системы соотношении</b>
<b><a name="z133"></a>  Часть 52. Определяем угол</b>
```

Пытаюсь пропарсить через preg_match_all с таким правилом

```
<(h3|p|a).*((id|name)="(z[0-9]+)"|).*>(.*)(РАЗДЕЛ|Раздел|раздел|ГЛАВА|Глава|глава|ЧАСТЬ|Часть|часть)(.*)(?(?=<\/a>)(.*)((<\/)b(>))(?!<b>)|<\/(h3|p)>)
```

выводит результат https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/Gcx
это делаю для того чтобы создать навигацию по блокам текста, по стандарту навигацию надо по "h3", "p" сделать, есть еще учитывать, то что есть и такой паттерн

```
<b><a name="z123"></a>#ТУТ_ТЕКСТ#</b>
```

если посмотрите на примере, то, там последний паттерн кое как сделал, но, он почему то берет и следующий такой текст если таковой существует.

Как сделать регулярку чтобы последнее вот до

```
</b>
```

только бралось? Или как можно улучшить вот это все с учетом того что, для такого паттерна

```
<b><a name="z123"></a>#ТУТ_ТЕКСТ#</b>
```

я делаю замену с добавлением id рядом с name

Comment: [Пожалуй, самый известный вариант этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @daniilkk видел, смешно) а как тогда предлагаете решить? Считать html в массив и там парится?) Задачу поставили, пытаюсь и решить.

Comment: Возможно будет проще воспользоваться готовыми решениями, php-html-parser например.. их много

Comment: Использовать парсеры XML\HTML.

Comment: Используйте парсер DOM/XML для создания модели и работайте с ней. И на будущее этот опыт пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Сам сделал регулярку чтобы вытащить такие html тэги.

```
(<b>|)<(p|a|h3).*((id|name)=\"(z[0-9]+)\")(.*)*>(.*)(?(?=<\/a>)<\/a>(.*)<\/b>|<\/(p|h3)>)
```

не могу использовать готовые библиотеки, т.к. просто напросто мне надо вытащить массив обработать их в цикле в ul li закинуть. Чем использовать эти готовые решения что портят время отрисовки страниц.

Всем спасибо за непомощь!